# How to put one dimensional array in 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of 16 integers (0-15) that i want to convert to a 4 by 4 2 dimensional array. How would i do that?

So far:

```
int [] array = new int[15]
int[][] array2 = new int[4][4]

for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
   for (int j=0;j<array2.length;j++)
```

I dont know what to put for the rest

Comment: These types of questions will always promote negative feedback.. You literally haven't attempted anything here...

Answer (score 0):

First, there are bugs in your original code: `array` should have 16 elements, not 15. Also, the end conditions for your loops are incorrect. Then add either

```
array2[i][j] = array[i*4 + j];
```

or, depending on whether you want row-major or column-major order:

```
array2[i][j] = array[j*4 + i];
```

Or more generally:

```
array2[i][j] = array[(i * width) + j];
```

Answer (score 0):

All u have to do is first initialize a variable k=0;
Then apply the following loop

`for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
array2[i][j]=array[k++];
}`

Here 4 can be replaced by the total number of rows in the first loop and total number of columns in the second loop for producing a generic code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner programmer however this is something that is very basic and once it is broken down into pieces it becomes very clear on what to do.

First you setup up your array (1D) and matrix (2D) to be of the same length (size). Which you have done incorrectly. 15x1 != 4x4. Should be 16x1 == 4x4.

```
int [] array = new int[16];
int[][] matrix = new int[4][4];
```

Secondly you simply need to write elements one by one from array to matrix. So you will need a loop that will iterate array.length (16, in this case) times. However BECAUSE you are working with a 2D array you will need a nested loop. So instead of using one loop that runs 16 times, use 2 loops (one nested inside of the other) that both run 4 times. The reason a nested loop is used here is to keep track of both the [row] and [col] of the matrix (2D array). Also we must create another variable to keep track of which array index we are currently on.

```
int arrayIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++){
        matrix[i][j] = array[arrayPosition];
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        arrayPosition++;
    }  
}
```

That's it. Now all elements from array are now also in the matrix. Hope that was clear enough.

Comment: Note that the end conditions in your inner for loop is incorrect and will only work if `matrix` is square. `for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)` will work in the general case.